# connection refused mysql node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've tried everything under the sun to fix this problem, nothing works!
I'm trying to connect to mysql using node.js.
I've tried both normal connections and pool connections, but I keep getting the following error:
"connect ECONNREFUSED"

I'm working on a Windows 7.

There are many similar questions to this on Stack Overflow, and everyone mentions the mysql configuration file (and commenting out "skip-networking"), however, I can't find where the file is (the mysql module was installed under node_modules). 
I've tried looking for my.ini and my.cnf, there don't seem to be on my machine either. 
Is there a way to try to log in to mysql via the command line?
It seems like there isn't since the command line doesn't recognize the command "mysql".

I'd post the code that I've been using but that wouldn't help, since I've been using dozens of different alterations, and all fail.

Thanks in advance, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Do you have MySql locally installed, or trying to connect to it remotely? Since mysql command doesn't work on your system, I suspect its remote.

Comment: i have it locally installed. That is, with npm install mysql

Comment: Dude, by executing that command, you installed MySql module, i.e. node.js - mysql driver. Not the MySql server. How will it work! Where will it connect?

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that, thank you. So a standard local installation of mysql will do the trick?

Comment: Yes, just install it locally, if you want remote server then you'll need to change those settings in `my.ini`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Салман, I realized that I need to install the actual MySQL server as well.